# How return another class type?

Tags: c++

I want to write something like that:

```
Map GameObject::CreateMap(){
    return (*(new MapCreator)) // there I want that MapCreator return Map type but MapCreator can only return itself 
}
```

What is the best solution for this case?

Comment: What *is* `MapCreator`? How would it be able to return a `Map`? Does it have a member function that creates a `Map`? Or does the `MapCreator` constructor create a `Map` object that you then want to access and return? And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: `*(new MapCreator)` is *always* wrong (and a memory leak)

Comment: And beware that the code you show have a memory leak. The object you create with `new` can never be deleted.

Comment: MapCreator it's class for creating map, and now idk how to return Map from it? (besides getter, but i don't want to use getter )
I can use unique_ptr instead *

Comment: There are two ways you can get a `Map` object from your `MapCreator` object: A conversion operator (which doesn't make much sense really), or a function to *get* the created `Map` object. If you do the latter you can simply do something like `return MapCreator().getMap();` (if `Map` follows [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

Comment: What's  conversion operator?

Answer (score -1):

A conversion MapCreator::operator Map() should be defined.

Comment: In my not very humble opinion, this is not a very good advice. Conversions between related types might be okay, but between unrelated types just makes for bad code that is hard to read and maintain.

Comment: It is possible that it is not a good style, but conversion is necessary that the function returns the Map object. Otherwise it returns the MapCreator.